# Chunking new sentences in Tagger Based NLTK Chunker

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, nltk

I am trying to implement one tagger based chunker in NLTK. 
I wrote the code as,

```
>>> import nltk,pprint,re,nltk.tree,string,codecs
>>> import nltk.corpus, nltk.tag
>>> import datetime
>>> from nltk.corpus import conll2000
>>> train_sents = conll2000.chunked_sents('train.txt', chunk_types=['NP'])
>>> test_sents = conll2000.chunked_sents('test.txt', chunk_types=['NP'])
>>> def conll_tag_chunks(chunk_sents):
    tag_sents = [nltk.chunk.tree2conlltags(tree) for tree in chunk_sents]
        return [[(t, c) for (w, t, c) in chunk_tags] for chunk_tags in tag_sents]

>>> tr_chunk = conll_tag_chunks(train_sents)
>>> te_chunk = conll_tag_chunks(test_sents)
>>> u_chunker = nltk.UnigramTagger(tr_chunk)
>>> accuracy=u_chunker.evaluate(te_chunk)
>>> print accuracy
0.832112628491
```

Things generally look fine, but I am unable to give new application sentence to classify. It may be something very silly but could not work out.

If anyone may kindly suggest

Comment: Try `u_chunker.tag()`. Though a unigram tagger isn't going to do much for you.

Comment: Thank you for the same. I tried it, but I am bit confused about the input, would it be tagged_sents() or sents() or something else?

Comment: Training data is always a list of pairs `(<input>, <desired output>)`. The corresponding tagger just takes the same kind of `<input>` You have trained a chunker that looks for named entities based on just their POS tag (throwing away the original words), so to use it you must also just pass a list of POS tags. If it's not any good, train a better chunker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Training data is always a list of pairs `(<input>, <desired output>)`. The tagger you train then takes the same kind of `<input>`. So take a look at your training input:

```
>>> print(tr_chunk[0][:5], "...")
[('NN', 'B-NP'), ('IN', 'O'), ('DT', 'B-NP'), ('NN', 'I-NP'), ('VBZ', 'O')] ...
```

You have trained a chunker that looks for named entities based on just their POS tag (throwing away the original words), so to use it you must also just pass a list of POS tags.

```
>>> words = "I sure love New York .".split()
>>> tags = [ t for (w, t) in nltk.pos_tag(words) ]
>>> u_chunker.tag(tags)
```

If it's not any good, train a better chunker.

Comment: Sir, Thank you for your kind reply, but seems generating an error,u_chunker.tag(t for (w, t) in nltk.pos_tag(words))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\tag\sequential.py", line 60, in tag
    for i in range(len(tokens)):
TypeError: object of type 'generator' has no len()

Comment: Getting results, [('PRP', u'B-NP'), ('VBP', u'O'), ('VB', u'O'), ('NNP', u'I-NP'), ('NNP', u'I-NP'), ('.', u'O')] as changed it slightly to u_chunker.tag([t for (w, t) in nltk.pos_tag(words)]). I am getting ['PRP', 'VBP', 'VB', 'NNP', 'NNP', '.'] from [t for (w, t) in nltk.pos_tag(words)]. Is it fine now?

Comment: I am changing conll_tag_chunks(chunk_sents):
with a new return as, 
[[(w, c) for (w, t, c) in chunk_tags] for chunk_tags in tag_sents]

it is enabling me identify NER with words with results as,
[('I', u'B-NP'), ('sure', u'O'), ('love', u'O'), ('New', u'B-NP'), ('York', u'I-NP'), ('.', u'O')]

I am trying to use custom training data now.

Comment: Sir, sure. But thanks for your pointer and time I could experimented out more and work out, [[((w, t),c) for (w, t, c) in chunk_tags] for chunk_tags in tag_sents] and that is coming very nice.

Comment: Much better. This is the correct way to train a chunker (also what the book shows).

Comment: If my answer allowed you to solve your problem, please "accept" it by clicking on the big check mark.

Comment: Sure Sir. I did it.